# Locking the size of a resizable window to the original aspect ratio of the window in Pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyglet

I'm making an image viewer, and I want it to resize only to scale factors of the original image size. In short, on resize, I want the entire image visible and no whitespace in the window. Is there any way to do this in pyglet? I've tried using the window.set_size() function, but I can't exactly figure out how to word the code so that it works the way I want it to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dear @NickTaber if you think the posted answer solved your problem or at least it was a useful clue to find the solution you were looking for, please don't hesitate to accept it. If you don't know how to accept an answer, here you can find more information about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this looks a little hackish for me, but at the moment I don't think of any other possibilities to solve you problem. Anyway, this is working:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window( resizable=True )

@window.event
def on_resize( width, height ):
    ratio = 9/16
    window.set_size( width, width*ratio )

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

pyglet.app.run()
```